# Dataframe in Spark is getting returning "d1: Unit = ()" after datediff transformation is applied

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Spark, I am writing a scala code in jupyter notebook to create a "datediff" calculation on a dataframe as below:

```scala
val d1 = t1.select(
  col("Order_ID"), col("Order_Date"), col("Ship_Date"),
  datediff(col("Ship_Date"), col("Order_Date")).as("Date_Diff")
  )
  .show(5)
Following is the o/p
+--------------+----------+----------+---------+
|      Order_ID|Order_Date| Ship_Date|Date_Diff|
+--------------+----------+----------+---------+
|CA-2018-152156|2018-11-08|2018-11-11|        3|
|CA-2018-152156|2018-11-08|2018-11-11|        3|
|CA-2018-138688|2018-06-12|2018-06-16|        4|
|US-2017-108966|2017-10-11|2017-10-18|        7|
|US-2017-108966|2017-10-11|2017-10-18|        7|
+--------------+----------+----------+---------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

The o/p given is correct however when I check `d1.getClass()`, the o/p given is "Class[Unit] = void"

I am able to understand how is a dataframe getting converting into a Unit class

Comment: method `show()` at the end of your  `d1` declaration returns Unit type, this is the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `show()` it returns no Dataframe, it just print it for debugging purposes

You can check it [here](https://dev.azure.com/repsol-digital-team/DAPlatform01/_git/dap-core-datafactory/pullrequest/16896?_a=files)

Just doing this:

```scala
val d1 = t1.select(col("Order_ID"),col("Order_Date"),col("Ship_Date")                  ,datediff(col("Ship_Date"),col("Order_Date")).as("Date_Diff")                     )

d1.getClass()
```

Should work fine